# При закрытии бургер меню, страница скролится на верх

Tags: html, css

Проблема заключается в том, что когда я открываю меню, а затем делаю скрол вниз и нажимаю закрыть, происходит скрол на верх страницы.

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
}

#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.menu__btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::before,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #616161;
}

.menu__btn>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.menu__btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="hamburger-menu">
    <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</body>
```

И я в упор не вижу в чем причина этого скрола.

Почему происходит скрол?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно убрать `position: fixed` для `label` и установить его для обертки `hamburger-menu`

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
}
.hamburger-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.menu__btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::before,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #616161;
}

.menu__btn>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.menu__btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="hamburger-menu">
    <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</body>
```